# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hadoop

I am using single node hadoop cluster (2.6.2),If there is any need to declare hdfs as distributed. I added the hdfs,core,common jar to project build path also required jar to project lib. But i now get error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation i configured hadoop in application context.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.2/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml"));


conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:8088");
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

Comment: At which line are you getting this exception?

Comment: last line FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);

Comment: Please Help me . This problem occurs many times ....

Comment: I will check and reply to the answer. Few months back I had looked at a similar problem and got it resolved. Can you post me your maven dependencies?

Comment: Actually, For this project I started using Maven. But later it gives problematic , so i change to plain JAVA EE Prespective.

Comment: Please give me your mail contact I will share this library with you..

Comment: Please Help me to solve this problem , Mr.  Manjunath Ballur

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3b20pBecu9JeXVFMEIxZjltY2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This Library for Checking....

Comment: I have answered the question. There seems to be a problem with your dependencies I tried it out in my environment. And it worked fine.

Comment: I tried this but it still occurs...

Comment: I configured hadoop context file below I attached this. check it

Comment: <hdp:configuration>
        fs.defaultFS=hdfs://localhost:8088
        hadoop.tmp.dir=/tmp/hadoop
        electric=sea
     </hdp:configuration>
</beans>

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the dependent jars that you are using.

I am using Hadoop 2.7.1.

I tried out your program and got a correct result in my cluster. I got the correct output `hdfs` as the scheme.

**Program:**

```
package com.myorg.hadooptests;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;

public class GetConfTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception    {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://MBALLUR:8020");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        System.out.println(fs.getScheme());
    }
}
```

**Maven dependencies:**

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**My classpath is set to (I am running this on Windows):**

> E:\HadoopTests\target>echo %CLASSPATH%
>   .;e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\etc\hadoop\;e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\
>   share\hadoop\common*;e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\common\lib*
>   ;e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\hdfs*;e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.
>   0-2557\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib*;e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\map
>   reduce*;e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib*;e:\hdp\ha
>   doop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\tools*;e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\sh
>   are\hadoop\tools\lib*;e:\hdp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\yarn*;e:\h
>   dp\hadoop-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557\share\hadoop\yarn\lib*